# Allow users to edit their profile fields in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, user-profile

I have a new question.

**What I want to do?**

I've created the profile for each player, now I want to allow users to edit their profile.

Part of this profile takes the `devise` table, with a second table called `profiles`.

*Devise:* Captures username, password and email

*Profiles:* Captures Personal Information

**Schema of Profiles**

```
  create_table "profiles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text   "about"
    t.string "fb"
    t.string "skype"
    t.string "birthday"
    t.string "twitter"
    t.string "steam"
    t.string "gender"
    t.string "occupation"
    t.string "location"
    t.string "interest"
  end
```

**My profile_controller.rb (Updated)**

```
class ProfileController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @profile = Player.all
    end

    def show
        @profile = Player.find_by(nick: params[:nick])
    end

    def edit
        # use this to populate a form in your view
         @profile = Player.find_by(nick: params[:nick])
    end

    def update
       @profile = Player.find_by(nick: params[:nick])
    if @profile.update_attributes(profiles_params)
         redirect_to(:action => "show", :profile => @profile.nick)
    else
       render("index")
    end
      end

  private
    def profiles_params
      params.require(:profiles).permit(:about, :skype)
    end
end
```

**Rake routes**

```
profiles GET    /profiles(.:format)              profiles#index
         GET    /profiles/:nick/edit(.:format)   profiles#edit
         GET    /profiles/:nick(.:format)        profiles#show
         PATCH  /profiles/:nick(.:format)        profiles#update
         PUT    /profiles/:nick(.:format)        profiles#update
```

**Routes.rb**

```
  devise_for :players

  resources :profile, param: :nick
  resources :profiles, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update], param: :nick
```

**Notes:**

1. I have a profile controller
2. I have these pages:

   - `show.html.erb`
   - `index.html.erb`

### **Now my question is:**

*How should I make the edit page for each users profile,
considering that each user edits their own profile?

Once a user edits a field, I want this to be reflected on the page `show.html.erb`. How can I achieve this?*

** show.html.erb **

```
<div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
  <div class="tab-pane fade active in" id="info">
     <p><div class="form-group">
        <label for="textArea" class="col-lg-2 control-label">About  <%= @profile.nick %></label>
     <div class="col-lg-10">
     <pre style="padding-bottom: 200px;"><%= @profiles.about %>(THIS IS THE ERROR)</pre>
    <span class="help-block">In Progress</span>
   </div>
  </div></p>
</div>
```

** edit.html.erb (Not _edit, because missing template)**

```
<strong>Testing About</strong>
            <%= form_for :profiles do |f| %>
            <%= f.label :about %>
            <%= f.text_field :about %>
            <div class="btn btn-primary">
                <a href="http://localhost:3000/profile/<%= @profile.nick %>">
                    <%= f.submit "Update Profile", :class => 'btn btn-primary' %></a>
                </div>
                <% end %>

                <% end %>
                <p>I am editing for</p> 
                <%= @profile.nick %>
```

*Thanks in advance*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Show* should be used to display a users profile, not edit it - this is the rails way.

I suggest you jump over and have a read on rails resourceful routing: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html - this covers routes and CRUD.

Consider you have your resource, :profiles - in your routes this can be declared as:

```
resources :profiles
```

This route will automatically create the desired routes for you - in this case we only seem to want index, show, edit and update therefore this can be declared:

```
resources :profiles, only: [:index, :show, :edit, :update]
```

We now have the following routes, i've commented what their purpose should be:

```
GET /profiles           #show all profiles
GET /profiles/:id       #show specific user profile
GET /profiles/:id/edit  #edit specific user profile
PATCH /profiles/:id     #update a specific profile
```

Now that we have our routes lets look at this from a controller perspective - i'm jsut going to focus on edit/update as this is your question:

```
class ProfileController < ApplicationController
    def index
      #do something
    end

    def show
        # do something
    end

    def edit
        # use this to populate a form in your view
        @profile = get_profile  
    end

    def update
       @profile = get_profile
    if @profile.update_attributes(profile_params)
       #do something on success
    else
       # do something on fail
    end
  end

  private
    def profile_params
      params.require(:profile).permit(:about, :skype, etc)
    end


    def get_profile
      nick = params[:nick]
      if Player.where(username: nick).present?
        if Player.where(username: nick).count == 1
          Player.includes(:profile).find_by(username: nick).profile
        else
          raise "Error: Multiple profiles found"
        end
      else
        raise "Error: Profile cannot be found"
      end        
    end
end
```

You'll notice the 'profile_params' method, this is apart of rails strong paramaters and whitelists the attributes we can use for mass assignment.  Read more: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html

Because our routes are set up as expected for our profile, our forms are super simple as rails can infer everything.

**edit.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @profile do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :about %>
   ... etc
   <% f.submit %>  # this will submit to profile#update
<% end %>
```

Further reading on form_for:  http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/form_for

Ofcourse you should also be adding authorisation to the controller methods but hopefully i've covered the basic premise for you.

**EDIT1:** In regards to your comment I've added a private method for locating your user profile by either username or id (tweak to suit).  But like I said, go through the linked readings so you can get an understanding of routing.

**EDIT2:** SO taking into consideration your further comments and the routes you added to the question i've updated your get_profile method.

Comment: Hmm, not work. I have the next error: 
'Couldn't find Profile with 'id'=AlexBanPer'

Forget to say that my model players looking for the "Username" parameter
Profile is the controller and Profiles is the table.

Comment: My model of devise is called 'Player'.

I am using the parameter of 'username', replacing the ID.

Now the problem that I have is that I can't figure out how to collect that information and put it in 'show.html.erb'. I am using  '<%= @profiles.about %>, but it appears to be an undefined method.

Comment: As far as modelling goes, how are the relationships setup between player and profile?  Ideally, Player has_one profile and Profile belongs to player.

Comment: Yes, player.rb => has_one: :profile ||||profile.rb => belongs_to :players

Comment: profile.rb should 'belongs_to :player' - not pluralised.  I'll re-adjust the get profile method shortly.

Comment: |||| Okey, now is belong_to :player. But in profiles/Alex/edit => SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: profiles.nick: SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."nick" IS NULL \\\\\//// LINE elsif Profile.where(nick: id).present?

Comment: One more question.  is 'nick' actually the devise username?

Comment: The model of devise is: 'player' || 'nick' is the name of the register.

Comment: Error: Profile cannot be found (localhost:3000/profile/alex/edit) || Why username?

Comment: Set it to whatever, just showing you across multiple models.